# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable Modeling in python

Tags: python, modeling

I am getting the following error in python, and I am not sure why. I am trying to model how meth affects mice.

Here is my code, and the functions that are created in my code:

```
from scipy import array, linspace
from scipy import integrate
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
def Temp2(z, t, Ta, Te, wexc, yexc, winhib, yinhib, whd, yhd, wexctoinhib, winhibtomdl, whdtospn, yspn, Tt):
    # Dependence of Meth Concentration 
    #    dx
    #    -- = -x/Ta
    #    dt
    #
    #    dy
    #    -- = x/Ta - y/Te
    #    dt
    # x = interperitoneal 
    # y = blood
    # Ta is the time constant of Meth in the absorbtion
    # Te is the time constant of Meth in elimination
    x = z[0] # Rabbits density
    y = z[1] # Sheep density
    T = z[2]
    D = int(x=1)
    yt = D(Ta/Te -1)**-1 * (e**-t/Ta - e**-t/Te)
    Pexc = (1+tanhx)*[wexc*yt*yexc]
    Pinhib = (1+tanhx)*[winhib*yt*yinhib]
    Phd = (1+tanhx)*[whd*yt*yhd]
    Pmdl = wexctoinghib*Pexc-winhibtomdl*Pinhib
    Pspn = Pmdl + whdtospn*Phd+yspn
    V = array([-x/Ta, x/Ta - y/Te, (Pspn-(T-T0))/Tt])
    return V

def main():
    # set up our initial conditions
    IC0 = 1
    BC0 = 0
    T0 = 37
    z0 = array([IC0, BC0, T0])

    # Parameters
    Ta = 8.25
    Te = 57.5
    wexc = 1.225
    yexc = -0.357
    winhib = 1.335
    yinhib = 1.463
    whd = 0.872
    yhd = -3.69
    wexctoinhib = 7.47
    winhibtomdl = 6.38
    whdtospn = 5.66
    yspn = -3.35
    Tt = 89.2

    # choose the time's we'd like to know the approximate solution
    t = linspace(0., 1., 60)

    # and solve
    xode= integrate.odeint(Temp2, z0, t, args=(Ta, Te,  wexc, yexc, winhib, yinhib, whd, yhd, wexctoinhib, winhibtomdl, whdtospn, yspn, Tt))
    print (xode)    
main()
```

Ignore the #s as they do not relate to what the code is saying. Here is the error I am getting:

```
yt = D(Ta/Te -1)**-1 * (e**-t/Ta - e**-t/Te)
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

I am not sure what is wrong, and how I can fix this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: `D` is an integer and you try to call it like a function `f()`.

Comment: you cannot omit the `*` for multiplication. `D(...)` means call `D` with args `...` not multiply `D * (...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here

```
yt = D(Ta/Te -1)**-1 * (e**-t/Ta - e**-t/Te)
```

There is no implicit multiplication in python, so when you attempt to do `D(Ta/Te - 1)` it is being interpreted as a function call rather than D multiplied by what is in the bracket.

Rewrite it like this

```
yt = D*(Ta/Te -1)**-1 * (e**-t/Ta - e**-t/Te)
```

Comment: I still have another error when I worked on the code and updated it.                                                                                                                                act = int(tanh(z[0]))                                                                                 Pec = (1+act)*(wexc*yt*yexc)
Pinhib = (1+act)*[winhib*yt*yinhib]
Phd = (1+act)*[whd*yt*yhd]
Pmdl = (wexctoinhib*Pec)-(winhibtomdl*Pinhib) 
Pspn = Pmdl + whdtospn*Phd+yspn
Error: Pmdl = (wexctoinhib*Pec)-(winhibtomdl*Pinhib)     
    TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'